# Using jquery with ASP.net and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

In my C# i used this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

    }
    protected void SubmitButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students (Name,City,Age) Values(@Name,@City,@Age)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NameText.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CityText.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Convert.ToInt32(AgeText.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        SuccessMessage.Visible = true;
        SuccessMessage.Text = "Successfully Inserted data";
        CityText.Text = "";
        NameText.Text = "";
        AgeText.Text = "";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "showalert();", true);

    }

}
```

And my ASPX:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .auto-style2
        {
            width: 163px;
        }

        .auto-style3
        {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .auto-style4
        {
            font-size: large;
        }

        .auto-style5
        {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .auto-style6
        {
            width: 112px;
        }

        .auto-style7
        {
            text-align: center;
            width: 163px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>



<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>insert succussfly</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <div>

            <div class="auto-style3">
                <span class="auto-style4">Inserting Data to DB<br />
                </span>
            </div>
            <table align="center" style="width: 41%; height: 179px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">Name:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameValidation" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="NameText" ErrorMessage="Name is reqiured"
                            Style="color: #FF0000; text-align: left">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">City:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CityText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style5">Age:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:RangeValidator ID="AgeValidation" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="AgeText" Display="Dynamic"
                            ErrorMessage="Age need to be between 20 to 50" MaximumValue="50"
                            MinimumValue="20" Style="color: #CC0000">*</asp:RangeValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="AgeText" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Age is required"
                            Style="color: #CC0000">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1" colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButtonClick"
                            Style="text-align: center" Text="Insert" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style7">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"
                Style="color: #CC0000" />

            <asp:Label ID="SuccessMessage" runat="server" Text="" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    show: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 1000
                    },
                    hide: {
                        effect: "explode",
                        duration: 1000
                    }
                });

                function showalert() {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    });
                }
        /*        $("#opener").click(function () {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                });*/
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to open the dialog after postback and it runs the alert function after finished the insert. Can you help me thanks.
I'm now getting showalert() is not defined.

Comment: what's wrong? What's your question? Are you getting javascript errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used javascript closure , and inside that you have `showalert`, so it will not be accessible to outside. For more info on closure read this - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp and [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

To make it work, please use this.

```
function showalert() {
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
}
```

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "showalert()",  true);`

**NOTE** - The code you are using `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student ....` is prone to SQL injection , you need to use parameterized query for this.

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Make sure you have included `jquery` and `jquery.ui` js files.

Comment: @Taha, updated code, try this!, i think you are definitely missing `jquery` and `jquery.ui` library after checking updated code, please add those to `aspx` , then it will work, there is no issue with the code now.

Comment: I'm getting : Uncaught ReferenceError: showalert is not defined

Comment: Where should i add the jquery and jquery.ui library? When i put it at header i get jquery is not defined but when i put it in body it don't show that error message. i use this <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, better to put in header. I have tried your example, it is working for me, have you tried my updated post?, you can try the similar solution by `Win`. I mean put `showalert` outside of `$(function () { .. }`.

Comment: OK it works now using :  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "$(function () { $('#dialog').dialog('open'); });", true);

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. I think you might be missing **jquery** and/or **jqueryui**.

Or you have script error in other part of your code. Create a stand along **aspx** page and test with the following code.

[image]

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server"
    Text="Submit"
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
    });
    function showalert() {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>insert successfully</p>
</div>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
        "script", "showalert();",  true);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch on the OP's question.  That could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the proper approach, you code actually looks correct (Aside you use jQuery UI `Dialog` rather than `Alert`. Here would be some items to help you a bit more.

```
function Submit() {
     if(!confirm("Are you sure you would like to submit?")) {
          return false;
     } else { 
          return true; 
     }
}
```

That particular function will act for a confirmation on the `on click` event.  Then for your front-end you would have:

```
<asp:Button 
      id="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
      OnClientClick="return Submit();" 
      OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

So when you hit the button, it will bring a `confirm dialog` up for the user.  On the code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do your database stuff, then to call Javascript from code behind.
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "ResponseToClient();", true);
}
```

Your calling a function called `ResponseToClient` and your wrapping it in the `<script>` tag.  So lets build our function:

```
function ResponseToClient() {
     alert("You successfully saved.");
}
```

Though the example is primitive it should provide more detail and information for you to make it useful for the User Experience correctly.  *Important: I usually if I do a call from code behind to front-end, I use a function.  It is often far more reliable and doesn't always error in the closure of your script tag.* Hope this gets you started.

*Noticed: Your code could be subject to SQL Injection.  You should use parameter approach:*

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ([Column] = @Id);";
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
     using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", parameter); // OR
          command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parameter;
     }
```

That is the proper approach, as it implements `IDispose` and properly parameterizes your query.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Arindam Nayak's comment, your showalert function is only valid inside the scope of the anonymous function defined at the top of your script : $(function () { ... }.

You just need to move the definition of the showalert function after the first function for it to work:

$(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
    });

```
function showalert() {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function